# How to cancel excluding a directory in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have opened a directory (**not** a saved project) in Sublime Text 3. Then, I right-clicked one of the subdirectories and selected `Project -> Exclude From Index (mark as binary) "/path/to/my/subdirectory/**"`. It seems to be permanent.

I tried the following sequence:

1. Quit Sublime Text 3
2. Rename the project folder
3. Open Sublime Text 3

The exclusion went away. Then I did the following:

4. Quit Sublime Text 3
5. Renamed the project directory back
6. Open Sublime Text 3

The exclusion came back as well. How can I cancel the exclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command isn't part of core Sublime, it's provided by the [SideBarEnhancements](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements) package. The name of the command in the menu is misleading; it doesn't do what it says it does.

It looks like it's saying that it will exclude that file from the index for the current project, but in fact excluding files from the index is accomplished via the `binary_file_patterns` setting:

```json
// These files will still show up in the side bar, but won't be included in
// Goto Anything or Find in Files
"binary_file_patterns": ["*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"],
```

This setting is a global setting that can't currently be set on a project by project basis, so despite the name of the command, it's really excluding that path from every project or Sublime window, not just from the one you run the command in.

In order to undo what it's doing, you need to open your user preferences by selecting `Preferences > Settings` (`Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings` if you are on MacOS) from the menu.

This will open a new window with the default settings on the left and your custom setting on the right. In the right side pane you can modify the `binary_file_patterns` setting to remove the path that you added in order to have it indexed again.

Comment: You are right. I didn't expect it to just edit the config.